# SAS FedSQL - regular expression

Tags: sql, regex, sas

I'm trying to use a regular expression inside the SAS Data Flux client, which uses Fed SQL. The code is like this:

```
select * from dataset
where char_value LIKE "ICM[DEF].*"
```

in order to match all the records where char_value = ICMD... or ICME... or ICMF... .
It doesn't seem to understand the regex, in fact it returns 0 rows.Can you help me?

Comment: In ANSI SQL double quotes are for identifiers (column names etc.), and single quotes for string literals. The `LIKE` wild-card is `%`. So try `LIKE 'ICM[DEF].%'` instead.

Answer (score 1):

After looking online for sas synatax, I saw that you are not using the correct syntax.

LIKE operator should be with singlee quotes if you are matching a string, and use % not * so:

```
select * from dataset
where char_value LIKE 'ICM[DEF]%'
```

Its untested, so tell me if it works(I'm not familiar with [] so if it doesn't work you can try like 'ICMD.%' or like 'ICME.%'....)

```
select * from dateset
where char_value like 'ICMD%' or char_value like 'ICME%' or char_value like 'ICMF%'
```

Comment: It doesn't like either the square bracket or the dot. I have to do 
    char_value LIKE 'ICMD%' or char_value LIKE 'ICME%'...

Comment: Sorry, I was saying that you're right, I have to do char_value LIKE 'ICMD%' or char_value LIKE 'ICME%'... to obtain the correct result.

Comment: Oh ok:) @MatteoFelici a V will be appreciated